# Phonegap 2.4 Facebook plugin Login doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I'am trying to use the facebook connect plugin with phonegap and I have a strange problem. I'am using my own phone (Samsung Galaxy Note II) to debug. I have installed the HackBook sample application.

When I start it and click on the "login to facebook" button, the local facebook apps starts and prompts the login page. I enter my FB credentials and instead of displaying my testing facebook app to grant, it displays the Samsung Galaxy Note II app ...

Now, if I remove the Facebook application from my phone, and I restart the hackbook application, the login button now displays the "web" version of the facebook login page and everything is working fine.

To sum up : If the facebook application is installed on my phone, the hackbook sample app uses it to perform the login step to facebook but it wants to grant the Galaxy Note II FB app instead of my own.

And if I remove the facebook application of my phone, everything works fine.

I need help

Thank you

Comment: Do you see anything strange in your Android logs (try the `CatLog` app or straight ADB) when you have the Facebook app installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the answer of chandra-kantha here :

Source (with screencaps) : https://github.com/amirudin/pgb-fbconnect/issues/1#issuecomment-26134737

---

Here is the fix for this problem.!!!

You will need to generate a hash of your Android key(s) and submit those to the Developers page on Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) to get it working. Furthermore, if you are generating this hash on Windows (specifically 64 bit versions),

please use version 0.9.8e or 0.9.8d of OpenSSL for Windows and not 0.9.8k.

Download openssl here: https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list.

Once you download the openssl , Extract the files and then open your openssl folder copy the path of bin folder then add to System Environment Variable Path.

Android Signing:

Adobe® PhoneGap Build™ allows you to sign your Android builds, so they are suitable for submission to the Android Market. To get a release build ready, you first need to generate a signing keystore file. Full details are available below:

Obtaining a suitable private key:

1) Download and install Java. http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp

2) Set Java_Home directory: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

3) Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as an Administrator, then Run the following command:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Please note the alias_name.

Keep all passwords "android"

4) Keytool will ask for keystore password. Enter password and confirm:

step_4_android_keystore_pass

5) Next, keytool will ask for additional information. Supply appropriately:
step_5_additional_info

6) Next, keytool will ask password for Alias. Return if it's the same as keystore password. Othewise enter password and confirm:

step_6_alias_password

7) Your signing key is now ready to submit:

step_7_keystore_ready

Submit to Build
8) Go to your Account > Edit Setting > Signing Key's tab.
step_8_edit_account_settings

9) Click 'add a key...' and supply the following info.
Title - anything
Alias - alias_name that you have given while generating the keystore file.

step_9_add_key

Unlocking the key.
10) Go to your Account > Edit Setting > Signing Key's tab:

step_10_edit_account_settings

11) Click 'lock' button and supply the following: Certificate password => refer step # 6. Keystore password => refer step # 4.

step_11_unlock_key

Generating New Hash Key

Now you will have to generate new hashkey using the keystore file that you have generated. Open your comand line and run the below command.

keytool -exportcert -alias [alias_name] -keystore [your_keystore_path\keystorefilename].keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Now copy the Hash key and add to your facebook app.

**Now make sure that you have selected the key on phonegap while building your app
build

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you add the key hash in Facebook App Dashboard (Native Android app section). You need to hash the key you use to sign the app. One more thing, Make sure the package name is correct and enable the Facebook Login.